# IBM Domino and authentication against Active Directory for web users

Tags: active-directory, xpages, lotus-domino

I have succesfully configured IBM Domino authentication against Active Directory for web users by following the 
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Streamlining_passwords_and_achieving_SSO_for_users_on_Windows_platforms .. and .. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21293255 tutorials. Now user can authenticate even there is no Person document in my Domino directory. Is there a way how to avoid authentication when Person document missing for particular user?

Based on this [tutorial](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Streamlining_passwords_and_achieving_SSO_for_users_on_Windows_platforms) and 'step 2' section I assumed, that when I dont specify LN user name in AD then Domino tries to find Person document in names.nsf based on user's email. But it doesnt work this way. Without specifying Notes name in AD, Domino server have no idea what is Notes user name for just authenticated user. Is here any way how to configure this in a way, that Domino authenticates only users available in names.nsf and not all these in AD?

Comment: Did you consider authorization instead?

Comment: The solution is usable as is ... its just my feeling that all AD users can authenticate to Domino. Using database ACL one can allow only valid users to enter in. My question is just a clarification request on documentation as it's not clear for me enough.

Comment: Yes, the settings in the server document that control access to the server can be used for that. But this is really a server admin question, not a development question, so it belongs over on ServerFault, not here.

Comment: Agree with Richard in regards to "ServerFault"; but let me add one thing: have you considered using a sync util like TDI? From what I know it's free to use for syncing AD to Domino, and in my opinion it gives you the best of both worlds. We are using it in various customer projects

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what You have and what You want to avoid, but, here are few notes that might clear things:

- You don't need DA for Kerberos SSO to work
- DA allows "all" AD users to login
- After login, You need authorization (as Frantisek Kossuth wrote)
- authorization can be set with AD names - You don't have to have Person documents
- TDI is best solution - You can "copy" just AD users that you want in Domino, and set SSO for them (you have already)